# Attach event to a dynamically created dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

In the code below I'm dynamically creating different posts.
Each post has its own image.

```
$(function () {
    for(post in data){
        //get from the data post details

        var titleData = data[post]["title"];
        var descriptionData = data[post]["description"];
        var imageData = "images/"+data[post]["image"];
        //create elements with jquery
        var postHolder = $('<div class="post row"></div>');
        var img = $('<img src="'+imageData+'" data-title="'+titleData+'" class="col-sm-3 img-post">');
        var textHolder = $('<div class="col-sm-9"></div>');
        var title = $('<h4 class="title-post"></h4>').append(titleData);
        var description = $('<p class="explanation-post"></p>').append(descriptionData);

        
        textHolder.append(title);
        textHolder.append(description);

        postHolder.append(img);
        postHolder.append(textHolder);
        $('.posts-container').append(postHolder);


        img.on('click',function(){alert(this.data-title);});

    }


});
```

I want that when I click the image, it will alert the title of the post (what's known as "titleData") and that the "textHolder" will change his background color to grey.

The limitation on this challenge are:

1. To pass a different parameter as the "titleData" each time.
2. To use minimum space in the memory.

Comment: Have you tried `alert(this.dataset.title)`

Comment: `this.data-title` is invalid javascript. names cannot contain the `-` symbol. To access the data attributes you can use the `dataset` of the object, like so: `this.dataset.title`.Otherwise, you can use the `$(this).data('title');` jQuery method.

What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is in the alert is wrong.

You are saying

```
this.data MINUS title
```

You sould be using bracket notation if the name has a dash in it.

```
alert(this["data-title"]);
```

or better with getAttribute

```
alert(this.getAttribute("data-title"));
```

or jQuery

```
alert($(this).data("title"));
alert($(this).attr("data-title"));
```

so the final code with the bg color change should be

```
img.on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr("data-title"));
    textHolder.css("background-color","#CCC");
    console.log(textHolder.css("background-color"))
});
```

Comment: great! do you have any recommendation about the second part of the question? (changing the background color of "textHolder" to grey)

Comment: `textHolder.css(...)` inside the click

Comment: but it won't recognise textHolder

Comment: `img.on('click',function(){alert( $(this).data("title") ); textHolder.css("background-color","red"); });` should work

Comment: no dude. you need to do closure somehow because it will change just the last one which was created.

Comment: @NoamIzhaki Um, unless the OP code is different, that is not the case.

Comment: (function(holder) {
            img.on('click', function() {
                alert($(this).attr("data-title"));
                holder.css("background-color","#CCC");
            });
            })(textHolder);

Answer (score 1):

`data-title` is invalid identifier in JavaScript. To access the  `data-*` attributes, You can use [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```
 alert(this.dataset.title)
```

OR, As you are using jQuery `.data()` method.

```
alert($(this).data("title"));
```

Comment: great! do you have any recommendation about the second part of the question? (changing the background color of "textHolder" to grey)